# automatically start/stop ALL scheduled tasks remotely

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

i have scheduled tasks on a windows 2003 server machine. i would like clients to be able to start/stop all the scheduled tasks on this machine. how can i do this?

Comment: I guess this could be done through remote registry edits. Though the concept continues to frighten me.

Comment: Could you define "clients" please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`net stop schedule` and `net start schedule` from the command line works.